# how to concate the cells which have blank values in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I want to save the excel file as .CSV format i used following code to save the file. but when i open this file using notepad it show's garbage values(symbols,no.).

```
Dim IntialName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
IntialName = "LIC"
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="LICMF_" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & "_final_report_IRMCa", FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
If sFileSaveName <> False Then
xlwkbInput1.SaveAs sFileSaveName
End If
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the garbage values?

Comment: How's the title related to the question?

Comment: You need to tell it the file format or it will default to an excel file format regardless of extension, so add xlCSV so it knows to *actually* save it as a csv file `xlwkbInput1.SaveAs sFileSaveName, xlCSV`